# File search.php is automatically renamed to search.php.off.php which brokes forum search

Tags: php, forum, vbulletin

I don't know what is happening. I have vBulletin forum and I have seen that file search.php is automatically renamed to search.php.off.php. So forum search and link "New posts" is broken. It has happened suddenly, I haven't changed any configuration. When I rename to search.php, it automatically renames back to search.php.off.php.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like it's something on the server, I'd ask your host.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

It turned out to be an anti-spam program. I found in the Syslog file that every four minutes the following line was run:
Mar  17 15:42:01 bx345 /USR/SBIN/CRON[30825]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/antyspam  > /dev/null 2>&1)

This was with a VPS account with a Polish hosting provider. The script was run by the hosting provider.